# Set a requirement for step response, like settling time, overshoot and static error of output

Tags: matlab, controller, controls, state-space

I'm trying to find the step response of the system below in picture and I need to find settling time, overshoot and static error of
output. How can I find them? Is what I programmed correct?

Matlab code :

```
A=[0,1,0,0;0,-42.44,212.24,0;0,0,0,1;0,0,0,-42.44];
B=[0;106.12;0;78.6];
C=[1,0,0,0;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1];
D=0;
sys = ss(A, B, C, D)
t=0:0.1:10;
figure;
step(sys,t,'r')
```

The system

[image: Controller and observer design]

Comment: Check out [`stepinfo`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/stepinfo.html)

Comment: @rinkert Hi sir, Thank you in advance. It gave me these info without any data  
                                                                                                                                               4×1 struct array with fields:

    [RiseTime
    SettlingTime
    SettlingMin
    SettlingMax
    Overshoot
    Undershoot
    Peak
    PeakTime]                                                                                                                  
and How can I find the static error?